# PHP MAILER sending multiple email to one recipient

Tags: php, yii, phpmailer

I know it may sound like duplicate but my problems a bit different
so i'm fetching email from my database use loop to get the data the problem was even if passing 1 email at the addaddress() function at a time all the recipient receive the same email multiple times based on the number of recipient example if my recipient is three each recipient will receive three email each this is my code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= (6) - 1; $i++) {
    $q = Yii::app()->db->createcommand("select user_other_email from user_account LIMIT 6")->queryall();
    $ty = '';
    for ($b = 0; $b < count($q); $b++) {
        $ty = $email = $q[$b]['user_other_email'];
        $msg = "Test this!";
        $adminemail = "email@gmail.com";
        $name=' = ?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($adminemail) . '?=';
        $subject = 'TEST';
        $headers = "From: $name <{".$adminemail."}>\r\n" . 
            "Reply-To: {$adminemail}\r\n".
            "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
            'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $this->mailsend2($ty,$adminemail,$subject,$msg);
    }
}
```

AND this is my mailer function:

```
public function mailsend2($to, $from, $subject, $message) {
    $mail = Yii::app()->Smtpmail;
    $mail->SetFrom($from, 'Test');
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
}
```

really dont know what is wrong with this

Comment: Well, neither do we if you wont' tell us what is going wrong?

Comment: By the looks of it there are two loops used here - the outer selects the same recordset 6 times and the inner sends an email to each recipient found in the outer query

Comment: actually there is no error my problem was each recipient receive the same email multiple times, if recipient is six each of them will receive 6 email @Epodax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code makes very little sense, and you're making it unnecessarily complicated. @RamRaider's comment is quite right. You're also doing lots of unnecessary work building strings you never use. Here's a more elegant implementation that should work as expected:

```
$q = Yii::app()->db->createcommand("select user_other_email from user_account LIMIT 6")->queryall();
foreach ($q as $to) {
    $this->mailsend2(
        $to['user_other_email'],
        'email@gmail.com',
        'TEST',
        'Test this!'
    );
}
```

This is still quite an inefficient way of sending. Look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) for a better implementation.

Comment: thank you for the corrections it helped, however i think somehow the email addressed got stuck to PHP mailer addAddress() function that is why all recipient receive multiple emails

Comment: No, because your call to `mailsend2` creates a new instance of PHPMailer every time, so it aways starts with an empty recipient list.

Comment: Actually I can't tell if it is doing that (because the instance is managed by Yii), but if it was you would see the first recipient being sent 1 message, then 2 messages, then 3, then 4, etc, not just everyone being sent everything. It's easily solved by adding `$mail->clearAllRecipients();` to `mailsend2, as is done in the example I linked to.

Comment: thanks again that is exactly what i did the looping is good but somehow YII  stacks all the email in addrecipient() i think. None the less thank you i got it working now.